# SDL image library linker

Tags: c++, codeblocks, linker-errors, sdl-2, sdl-image

I've read many posts on `SDL_Image` library, but I still cannot solve my problem.

I have `#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"` at the top, but when I go to compile it says

> "cannot find -lSDL_image".

I have the `SDL2_image.dll` with the main, double checked that I have the correct versions of both SDL and SDL_image, and have also tried "`SDL_image`" under the linker options, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link to SDL_image (for SDL 1.2), but what you really want is to link to SDL2_image (for SDL 2.0+).  Try changing your linker options to point to SDL2_image and change your include line to point to the SDL2_image header (likely "SDL2/SDL_image.h").